# Changing a class's property from another class

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class with properties:

```
public class TaskConfiguration 
{
    public string Task_Name
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public string task_id
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

And somewhere in the code I have a method to set the properties of the class early on upon program execution:

```
public class TaskManagingProcess
{
    public void InsertTaskProperties()
    {
        TaskConfiguration tc = new TaskConfiguration();
        tc.Task_Name = "Sample Task";
        tc.task_id = "1";
    }
}
```

Later in execution, in another class, I want to modify the properties of the `TaskConfiguration` class, but I'm not sure how.  If I use the following, it will not work because it creates a new instance of the `TaskConfiguration` class.

```
TaskManagingProcess tmp = new TaskManagingProcess;
tmp.InsertTaskProperties();
```

So how can I do this?

Comment: Do you have an instance of your TaskConfiguration in the other class? Perhaps you should add parameters to your InsertTaskProperties method?

Comment: Could you pass a reference to the `TaskConfiguration` instance to the other class?

Comment: your `tc` instance "dies" (becomes out of scope and is garbage collected) as soon as your `InsertTaskProperties` method finishes. You need to read about [scopes](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpVariableScopes.aspx)

Comment: @HighCore yea, I realized that.  If I put the tc instance at the class level, then the tc instance gets set properly.  But I could never modify the original tc instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to pass the object:

```
public void InsertTaskProperties(TaskConfiguration config) {
    config.Task_Name = "Sample Task";
    config.task_id = "1";
}
```

Then:

```
TaskManagingProcess tmp = new TaskManagingProcess();
TaskConfiguration config = new TaskConfiguration();

tmp.InsertTaskProperties(config);
```

(I am making an awfully large assumption about your code.. but this should give you the basic idea)

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like TaskManagingProcess is a proxy class that's why I would recommend something like:

```
 public class TaskConfiguration 
    {
        public string Task_Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string task_id
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }


public class TaskManagingProcess
{
    private TaskConfiguration taskConfiguration;

    public TaskManagingProcess(TaskConfiguration taskConfiguration)
    {
        this.taskConfiguration = taskConfiguration;
    }

    public void InsertTaskProperties(string taskId, string name)
    {
        taskConfiguration.task_id = taskId;
        taskConfiguration.Task_Name = name;         
    }
}
```

So at the end you could do this (see below) and easily add code to handle the access at your TaskConfiguration object:

```
TaskConfiguration taskConfiguration = new TaskConfiguration() { task_id = "1", Task_Name = "Sample Task" };
TaskManagingProcess taskManaginProcess = new TaskManagingProcess(taskConfiguration);

taskManaginProcess.InsertTaskProperties("2", "Sample Task 2");
```